# Set autocomplete off in a form for just some fields

Tags: html, autocomplete

I have a form where I want to turn off the autocomplete feature for some of the fields. In my tests, turning off the autocomplete is turning it off for the ***whole*** form, which is not what I want. This is what I do:

```
<form>
  <input name="a">
  <input name="b" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

I have some questions:

- Is this the expected behaviour? Not from what I have been reading ...
- How can I disable autocomplete for just *some* fields?

Comment: See this [StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Comment: My case is very specific: autocomplete="off" *is* working, but too broadly (all fields in the form, even by putting it in only one field). Is this expected?

Comment: Whilst I don't pretend to know what you're problem truly is, there could be a number of problems: what browser are you testing this in? What is your HTML file `DOCTYPE`? 

You'll notice that in the other answer, someone mentions that "_...Autocomplete is only defined in the HTML 5 standards_" so if your `DOCTYPE` is wrong, you may be trying to apply an HTML5 standard on a non-HTML5 page.